# AC load line of a BJT

Tags: ac, bjt, biasing

I have not understood what the AC load line for a BJT is and while drawing the AC load line for a BJT, the collector emitter voltage ***VCE*** and the collector current ***IC***  are related as,

***IC = -VCE / (RC // RL)***

Where ***RC*** is collector resistance and ***RL*** is the load resistance.

So, according to this equation, the load line should pass through origin but that does not happen. Why doesn’t it happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Load line will be solving equation for IC = 0, then VCE = 0.  It cannot get to the origin.

Comment: I think, the shown equation is not correct. Vce is not the voltage across Rc||RL

Answer (score 1):

There are **two equations** which must be fulfilled **at the same time**:

(1) BJT: **Ic=f(Vce)** for a varity of different Ib values

(2) Collector resistor: Ohms law with **(Vcc-Vce)=Ic*Rc** (Assumption: Without emitter resistor)

We are using a common system of two axis (Ic, Vce) for finding the crossing where both equations can be fulfilled. For this purpose, we have nothing else to do than solve the second equation for the current: **Ic=(Vcc-Vce)/Rc** .

That is the so-called load line. Now we have two functions Ic=f(Vce) which can be drawn in a common diagram. The crossings show the possible operational points. If there is a an additional load resistor Rload (connected to the collector) it must be considered separately:

(a) DC-coupled (without a coupling capacitor): Replace Rc with Rc||Rload.

(b) AC coupled (with a capacitor): There is new AC load line with another slope (if compared with the DC load line) which goes through the selected DC operational point (it crosses the DC load line).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this concept but in a quite different manner than the conventional formal explanation. I hope it will be also useful for you.

The idea of this graphical representation is to reduce the circuit to two 2-terminal elements - a *real voltage source* with some internal resistance and *varying load* (the collector-emitter part of the transistor). They are connected to each other (both in series and parallel) so the same voltage is across them and the same current flows through them. Each of them is represented by its IV curve. The intersection (operating) point gives the circuit solution (the voltage and current).

The IV curve of the real voltage source is what is named "load line". When the transistor changes its collector current, the moving intersection point pictures the "load line". Its slope is determined by the equivalent internal resistance. In DC mode, it is only Rc; in AC mode, it is Rc||RL.

To imagine the latter, think of the coupling capacitors as of a short connection; then, Rc and RL form a voltage divider. Its output (Thevenin) resistance is Rc||RL.